# Correctly ending a sentence with "?" or "!" spacing?

Tags: novel

Specifically, should there be a space after a sentence last letter or directly after the written last letter ?  I personally prefer a space (to me, the text is clearer to read) but perhaps (grammatically) I should write without a space ?  Please advise.

Comment: What have you tried so far to find an answer? It helps to know that we're not just sending you back to resources you've already looked at.

Comment: I have already searched online but found no reference answer or opinion to my question.

Comment: So I think this is a duplicate of [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4645/is-it-ever-correct-to-have-a-space-before-a-question-or-exclamation-mark) on English.SE (but can't mark duplicates between sites)

Answer (score 5):

You should never leave a space between the end of a sentence and punctuation marks that is what all grammar references say.

Answer (score 2):

The '!' or '?' are the [sentence-terminating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_punctuation) characters that are replacing the fullstop '.' so you do the same spacing for all three, i.e. none.

Assuming you're writing in English that is, the usage is different in different languages (French for example has a space before '!' and '?').